# Excel: I want to assign an hour-of-day cost to outages based on when they happened

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet of outage records with start and end times.  I have another spreadsheet that shows how many customers typically use the system during any specific hour of a specific weekday and a cost per customer that gets routed to customer care instead of being handled by self-service.  I want to use a complex formula, preferably (rather than VBA, if possible), that can look at the outage time, determine how many minutes in each hour are "outage minutes", how many customers would be impacted during that many minutes of that hour and return a final cost.

For example:

Hourly Customer Volume Table

```
Hour  Customers
0     50
1     150
2     500

Outage record
Outage start:  0:35 (h24:mm)
Outage end:  2:42  (h24:mm)
```

Correct answer the forumula(s) should deliver the final total value below:

- Hour 0, 25 minutes of outage at customer impact rate of 50/hour,
- Hour 1, 60 minutes of outage at customer impact rate of 150/hour,
- Hour 2, 42 minutes of outage at customer impact rate of 500/hour,

Sum of (((25/60)*50)+((60/60)*150)+((42/60)*500)) = 520.83 customer impacts.

So far my best idea is to use a whole mess of formulas:

- one for each hour to calculate how many minutes of the outage were in that specific hour of the day
- another for each hour to multiple the outage minutes in that hour by the customer contact rate for that hour
- and then a simple formula to total up all the (hourly-minutes * hourly customer contact rate) sums.

I have reasonable fluency with building formulas in Excel but I certainly am not familiar with all of the options.  I've recently had good success with things like sumif/sumifs and I've built more nested if formulas than I can count.

How can I accomplish this "weighted impact cost" calculation with any reasonable level of efficiency?

Comment: Perhaps use a lookup table and vlookup()

Answer (score 1):

make sure the times are true times without a date part and use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(HOUR(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,(B7*24*60)):INDEX(XFD:XFD,B8*24*60-1))/(24*60)),A2:A4,B2:B4)/60)
```

[image]

---

If the times include a date then use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(HOUR(ROW(INDEX(XFD:XFD,MOD(B7,1)*24*60):INDEX(XFD:XFD,(B8-TIME(0,1,0)-B7+MOD(B7,1))*24*60))/(24*60)),A2:A4,B2:B4)/60)
```

[image]

Comment: This method looks like it could work but I'll need to add some logic - the start time and end time are date/time values like "2016/04/12 18:00", I figured I'd need to use something like the "hour" and "minute" functions to extract the hour and minute.  And some logic like "if start hour <= hour table current row AND end hour >= hour table current row THEN multiplier for this hour = 60", so that if the impact starts on 1/1/2000 at 00:23 and ends on 1/1/2000 at 22:17, all of the hours in between would be included.  I'm not sure how to do that logic without VBA or a full table of functions.

Comment: Are they always the same day?

Comment: @AHH see edit, I added one if there is a date added and it does not mater if the times are on different date, only requirement now is that the start  is less then the end.